# Distance between latttude and longitude

Tags: python

Friends,
I am working on something to find out distance between two latitude and longitude points.

Below is my python code, to get the distance in KM

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def distance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2):     
    R = 6371  # radius of the earth in km
    lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2 = map(radians, [lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2])
    x = (lng2 - lng1) * cos( 0.5*(lat2+lat1) )
    y = lat2 - lat1
    d = R * sqrt( x*x + y*y )
    return d

distance(25.42684996,81.84835984,25.45328992,81.86906992)
**Out[77]: 3.6011256577543027**
```

The answer is 3.60.. km. But when i cross check in google maps it says 609 km. Can any one suggest what is the mistake here?

i referred [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and other links too

Its absolutely fine, if you have "R" - code !!!

Also, is there any way that i can find out shortest route that google proposes, in python?

Comment: Are you sure you did the Google Maps check correctly? Those points don't look that far apart to me.

Comment: Only look at your lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2. In my opinion 609km it's the wrong answer and 3,6km it's the right answer.

Comment: Your formula seems wrong to me, you're missing tans and operations, look at Haversine formula to calculate distance between 2 coordinates

Comment: Google Maps gives me 4,5km walking distance between the two points.

Comment: Use the Google Maps API for your second question.

Comment: It's 3.59km, measured in ArcMap, so not sure where 609 km came from.

Comment: looks like am still not able to get the solution.. this time i am searching by city name directly (from Mutthi Ganj to Anjana Uttar Pradesh, India) https://www.google.co.in/search?ei=dR3OWpiAIoSUvQTHu7jQAg&q=Mutthi+Ganj+to+Patel+Churaha+Bus+Stop+distance&oq=Mutthi+Ganj+to+Patel+Churaha+Bus+Stop+distance&gs_l=psy-ab.3...55634.57557.0.57776.2.2.0.0.0.0.334.526.0j1j0j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.wEO13C0pPBo for the co-ordinates great_circle_distance((25.42684996,81.84835984),(25.37993,82.1407999)) i get 29.00 km... in python.. but above link shows 162.6 km..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
from math import *

def greatCircleDistance((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)):
  def haversin(x):
    return sin(x/2)**2 
  return 2 * asin(sqrt(
      haversin(lat2-lat1) +
      cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * haversin(lon2-lon1)))
```

This returns the angular distance between the points on a sphere. To get a distance in length (kilometers), multiply the result with the Earth radius.

Comment: Hi Hari.. thanks for the solution.. i found similar to you solution here https://gist.github.com/gabesmed/1826175 ,, as your code throwing error.. may be "x" substitution not happening.. correct me if am wrong.. its 3.69 km only..